# Vue.js: Data is not reactive and not correctly updated within a method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a custom component which receives a list of filters in order to display just the doctors that the user has selected:

```
<DoctorsSidebarFilter @update-view='showFilteredDoctors'></DoctorsSidebarFilter>
```

Next, in my main component, I'm using this to display the doctors:

```
<v-flex
   v-for="doctor in allDoctors"
   :key="doctor.first_name"
   xs12
   sm6
   md4
>
```

And here's my data:

```
export default {
data: () => ({
        allDoctors:[],
    }),
    methods: {
        fetchDoctors(){
            //Retrieve doctors
            this.$store.dispatch(RETRIEVE_DOCTORS)
            .then(
                response => {
                    this.allDoctors = response;
                }
            )//TODO-me: Handle the error properly!
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        },
        showFilteredDoctors(filters){
            let result = [];
            this.fetchDoctors();

            console.log('1:' + " " + JSON.stringify(this.allDoctors));
            if (filters.length > 0) { // If Array is not empty then apply the filters
                console.log('2');
                this.allDoctors.forEach(function(e) {
                    if(filters.some(s => s.specialty === e.specialty || s.city === e.city)) {
                        result.push(e);
                    }
                });
                console.log('3:' + " " + JSON.stringify(result));
                this.allDoctors = [...result];
                console.log('4:' + " " + JSON.stringify(this.allDoctors));
            }
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.fetchDoctors();
    }
}
```

The problem is that eventhough my filtering works correctly and I can see from `console.log('4:' + " " + JSON.stringify(this.allDoctors));` that `this.allDoctors` contains the new, filtered list; this is never displayed on screen.

Instead I see the default list of doctors that I've fetched from my API. Using vue devtools I can see that the `this.allDoctors` is *momentarily* updated with the correct values but then it goes back to the default ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As **@user1521685** has already explained, the call to `fetchDoctors` is asynchronous so it'll complete after you've performed the filtering.

Typically you'd do something like this using a computed property instead and only make the server call once.

```js
export default {
    data: () => ({
        allDoctors: [],
        filters: []
    }),
    computed: {
        filteredDoctors() {
            const allDoctors = this.allDoctors;
            const filters = this.filters;

            if (filters.length === 0) {
                return allDoctors;
            }

            return allDoctors.filter(doctor => {
               return filters.some(filter => filter.specialty === doctor.specialty || filter.city === doctor.city);
            });
        }
    },
    methods: {
        fetchDoctors(){
            //Retrieve doctors
            this.$store.dispatch(RETRIEVE_DOCTORS)
            .then(
                response => {
                    this.allDoctors = response;
                }
            )//TODO-me: Handle the error properly!
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        },
        showFilteredDoctors(filters){
            this.filters = filters;
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.fetchDoctors();
    }
}
```

In your template you'd then use:

```html
v-for="doctor in filteredDoctors"
```

Comment: I figured this would be somekind of problem due to async. It works now, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`fetchDoctors` is async, so in `showFilteredDoctors` you fetch the doctors, then set the filtered array and then the thenable in `fetchDoctors` kicks in and overrides the doctors again: `this.allDoctors = response`.
You'd have to return the Promise in `fetchDoctors` and use it in `showFilteredDoctors` like so:
`this.fetchDoctors().then(() => /* do the filtering */)`

EDIT: Return the Promise like this:
`return this.$store.dispatch(RETRIEVE_DOCTORS).then().catch()`